# Sync php calendar with outlook

Tags: php, outlook, synchronization

I want to create a calendar on the internet that can sync with my outlook. My calendar values are in a database. But how can I sync or auto-sync my database to outlook? 
Searched on the internet for a while but can't find anything that suits my problem.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "sync"?

MSOutlook can publish a simplified version of its calendar in iCAL format to an FTP or WebDav server - and it can import ical files - but this is a [very long way from 'sync'ing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Outlook#Calendar_compatibility).

ActiveSync is probably the right tool for implementing integration but a quick google suggests that there is no support for direct iCAL integration (there are products like AtMail - but these only provide a very basic publish capability).

There is at least one [shareware program](http://www.calendar-import-export.com/) which seems to meet the bill.

Comment: My meaning of sync is that there runs a program in the background that constant keeps track of my online agenda. If there changes something it must sync with my outlook. I also found the iCalendar but and I can add events in my calendar but it is not the thing that I need.

Comment: Your meaning of sync is "changes ... must sync with my outlook"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at something like the iCalendar format .ics, i'm pretty sure that Outlook can read those files and they are pretty simple to write

Answer (score -3):

You can perform mail function with PHP by using the *Mailparse* functionality.

*Mailparse* allows you to perform various operations such as checking mail formats, storing data to databases or to save files. Check the PHP website www.php.net

http://www.2createawebsite.co.za